# Visibility depending on several values of another field

Tags: forms

I'm having a form with two field. And visibility of the one is depending on the values of the other.

```
    $form['property'] = array(
    '#title' => t('Property'),
    '#type' => 'radios',
    '#options' => array(
        'private' => t('Private'),
        'bail' => t('Bail'),
        'lease' => t('Lease')
    ),
    '#required' => TRUE,
);


$form['bank'] = array(
    '#title' => t('Bank / leasing company'),
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#required' => TRUE,
    '#states' => array(
            'visible' => array(
                ':input[name="property"]' => array('value' => 'bail'),
            ),
        ),

);
```

What comes to `':input[name="property"]'`. How do I make it visible when `"bail"` OR `"lease"` values are set?

Answer (score 2):

The [Conditional Fields](http://drupal.org/project/conditional_fields) module should be able to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Ajax, both a [Wrapper](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--topics--forms_api_reference.html/forms_api_reference.html#ajax_wrapper) and a [callback](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--topics--forms_api_reference.html/7#ajax_callback). The wrapper will be set to be hidden by default with a little function to determine the set value of `$form['property']` if it is `"bail"` OR `"lease"`

Comment: Thank you very much. But I'm new to drupal and not very familiar with it.
Can you please show it to me?